Given a positive definite matrix $B$, and an equation $s B s^T=s_1$ where $s=(s_1,...,s_N)$, can we find solution with $s_1>1$ and $s_i<0 (i \neq 1)$.
I have a symmetric positive definite matrix $B$, and an equation $$s B s^T=s_1$$ where $$s=(s_1,...,s_N),$$ can we find solution $s$ with $s_1>1$ and $s_i<0 (i \neq 1)$?
Assume $B=C C^T$, then the equation becomes $$D_1^2+D_2^2+...+D_N^2=s_1$$ where$$D=sC$$
If this conclusion is not always correct, I will be very glad if you could tell me what kind of $B$  can make this equation has the kind of solution I want.
